# Program not completing all the way through

Tags: java, filewriter, printwriter

Im trying to create a program that takes an input file that contains lines of integers indicating a number of spaces and, alternately, characters to be printed to create a picture. The first integer on a line will always be a number of spaces to print(this may be 0). Every alternate integer will be a number of characters to print. The last integer on a line will always be -1, flagging the end of the line. For example, the line 0 2 4 2 -1, would represent "0 spaces - 2 characters - 4 spaces - 2 characters - next line." The characters can be anything such as "#" or "%"

This is what I have so far...

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class PicturePrinter
{
private Scanner fileScanner;
private FileWriter fwriter;
private PrintWriter outputFile;

public PicturePrinter(File file, boolean appendToOutputFile) throws IOException
{
    fileScanner = new Scanner(file);
    if (appendToOutputFile)
    {
        fwriter = new FileWriter("output.txt", true);
        outputFile = new PrintWriter(fwriter);
        printPicture(true);
        outputFile.close();
    }
    else
    {
        printPicture(false);
    }
    fileScanner.close();
}

//***************

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    String infileName;
    Scanner keyboard =  new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean badFile;
    File file;
    System.out.println("This program prints pictures from input files.");
    System.out.println("Do you need a picture printed? (y or n): ");
    String answer = keyboard.nextLine();
    while (answer.charAt(0) == 'y' || answer.charAt(0) == 'Y')
    {
        do
        {
            System.out.print("Enter your input file's name: ");
            infileName = keyboard.nextLine();
            file = new File(infileName);
            if (!file.exists())
            {
                badFile = true;
                System.out.println("That file does not exist.");
            }
            else
            {
                badFile = false;
            }
        }
        while (badFile);
        System.out.print("Would you like to export the picture to output.txt? (y or n): ");
        answer = keyboard.nextLine();
        if (answer.charAt(0) == 'y' || answer.charAt(0) == 'Y')
        {
            PicturePrinter pp = new PicturePrinter(file, true);
        }
        else
        {
            PicturePrinter pp = new PicturePrinter(file, false);
        }
        System.out.print("Would you like another picture printed? (y or n): ");
        answer = keyboard.nextLine();
    }
}

public static void printPicture(boolean picture)
{
    Scanner key =  new Scanner(System.in);
    while (key.hasNextLine())
        {
            if (key.hasNextInt() && key.nextInt() != -1)
            {
                int space = key.nextInt();
                System.out.format("[%spaces]%n", "");
                int chars = key.nextInt();
                System.out.format("[%charss]%n", "#");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println();
            }
       }
  }
 }
```

Everything compiles alright but when I run the program, it goes blank after it gets an answer for exporting the picture. Just doesnt anything afterward. I think its the printPicture method at the bottom of the code that is messing it up. I just dont know what to do to fix it.

the input files look like this

```
4 3 3 -1
2 4 1 1 2 -1
1 1 1 1 1 2 1 1 1 -1
0 3 2 1 1 3 -1
5 1 4 -1
2 3 1 3 1 -1
1 5 1 3 -1
1 3 1 1 1 1 1 1 -1
1 5 1 3 -1
2 3 1 3 1 -1
```

Comment: new Scanner(System.in); - do you want to print user input?

Comment: yeah.  what is your `printPicture` method supposed to do?  Why do you think it's "messing it up"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`hasNextLine()` and `hasNextInt()` are blocking methods that expect input. You're suppose to provide the input from the file but instead you set the scanner to `Scanner key =  new Scanner(System.in);` in the method `printPicture()` - which is why the method hangs forever.

Answer (score 0):

The `printPicture` method should read from the file, not from the standard input. In other words, you're using the wrong scanner in `printPicture`. Remove the `key` scanner, and use `fileScanner` instead.